# How to add delimiter to String after every n character using hive functions?

Tags: sql, string, hive, hiveql, delimiter

I have the hive table column value as below.

```
"112312452343"
```

I want to add a delimiter such as ":" (i.e., a colon) after every 2 characters.

I would like the output to be:

11:23:12:45:23:43

Is there any hive string manipulation function support available to achieve the above output?

Answer (score 2):

For fixed length this will work fine:

```
select regexp_replace(str, "(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})","$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:$6")
from
(select "112312452343" as str)s
```

Result:

```
11:23:12:45:23:43
```

Another solution which will work for dynamic length string. Split string by the empty string that has the last match (`\\G`) followed by two digits (`\\d{2}`) before it (`(?<= )`), concatenate array and remove delimiter at the end (`:$`):

```
select regexp_replace(concat_ws(':',split(str,'(?<=\\G\\d{2})')),':$','')
from
(select "112312452343" as str)s
```

Result:

```
11:23:12:45:23:43
```

If it can contain not only digits, use dot (`.`) instead of `\\d`:

```
regexp_replace(concat_ws(':',split(str,'(?<=\\G..)')),':$','')
```

Comment: Hi buddy :-) Check my answer for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite simple if you're familiar with regex & lookahead.
Replace every 2 characters that are followed by another character, with themselves + ':'

```
select regexp_replace('112312452343','..(?=.)','$0:')
```

---

```
+-------------------+
|        _c0        |
+-------------------+
| 11:23:12:45:23:43 |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: great, finally the best solution